# Filtering through pytesseract results using regex

Tags: python, regex, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using `pytesseract` to extract names from images (the images are the bouding boxes of the names so it's just the name by itself with nothing else)

I get good results but because my roi selection isn't very good sometimes I get bounding boxes on stuff I don't care for.

I got the idea to apply `pytesseract-engine` to all the images and then only save the ones where the return value on them was all caps and different from two specific words that are all caps but that I still don't care for.

This is the code:

```
# Adding custom options
folder = r"C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\SoftOCR_Final\names"
custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
words = []
regex = r"\b[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*\b"
for img in glob.glob(rf"{folder}\*.png") or range(20):
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=custom_config)
    if re.search(regex, text) and text != 'NOM' and text != 'PRENOM':
        words.append(text)
print(words)
```

I still get values like this: highlighted in bold

> ['HAREFED\n\x0c', 'ACHRAF\n\x0c', 'MANSOUR\n\x0c', **'Nom et Prénom
> Surveillant(s)** | **Signature(s)\nTE Rakes** |**nFabel Sha!** ——
> |\n|\n\x0c', 'ZAOQUAM\n\x0c', 'OUMAYMA\n\x0c']

I only want values like these names: highlighted in bold

> ['**HAREFED**\n\x0c', '**ACHRAF**\n\x0c', '**MANSOUR**\n\x0c', 'Nom et
> Prénom Surveillant(s) | Signature(s)\nTE Rakes |\nFabel Sha! ——
> |\n|\n\x0c', '**ZAOQUAM**\n\x0c', '**OUMAYMA**\n\x0c']

Someone help please, I feel like I'm very close to cracking this. I could be wrong though; I'm really only a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do, but if you're looking to grab all-caps words you can do:

```
re.match('[A-Z]+$', text.rstrip())
```

Note I'm getting rid of the garbage at the end of the string so it just turns into a word with all-caps. Is that what you want here?

```
>>> [re.match(r'[A-Z]+$', s.strip()) for s in ['HAREFED\n\x0c', 'ACHRAF\n\x0c', 'MANSOUR\n\x0c', 'Nom et Prénom Surveillant(s) | Signature(s)\nTE Rakes |\nFabel Sha! —— |\n|\n\x0c', 'ZAOQUAM\n\x0c', 'OUMAYMA\n\x0c']]
[
    <re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='HAREFED'>,
    <re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='ACHRAF'>,
    <re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='MANSOUR'>,
    None, 
    <re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='ZAOQUAM'>,
    <re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='OUMAYMA'>
]
```

And if it is as simple as that, then you don't need a regex as all, just check if text == text.upper():

```
>>> terms = ['HAREFED\n\x0c', 'ACHRAF\n\x0c', 'MANSOUR\n\x0c', 'Nom et Prénom Surveillant(s) | Signature(s)\nTE Rakes |\nFabel Sha! —— |\n|\n\x0c', 'ZAOQUAM\n\x0c', 'OUMAYMA\n\x0c']
>>> [s.strip() for s in terms if s==s.upper()]
# ['HAREFED', 'ACHRAF', 'MANSOUR', 'ZAOQUAM', 'OUMAYMA']
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much